# Запуск программы на go

Tags: golang, windows, windows-7

Здравствуйте!
Объясните, пожалуйста, пошагово что нужно сделать.
У меня стоит `windows 7`.
Мне нужно запустить программу на языке программирования `GO`.
Что для этого нужно установить и настроить?
Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: ни как я не запустил
прописывал разные пути все без толку
может я что то ни так делаю
тестовый файл лежит
на C:\Go\test\helloworld.go
прописывал путь по разному то синтактическая ошибка, то не верно задано имя, то the system cannot find the path  specified

Comment: прописал вот такой путь
cd<c:\go\test\>go run helloworld.go
написано отказано в доступе

Comment: @schumakow, когда просто в командной строке вызываете команду **`go`**, то что на экране видите?

Comment: много чего написано

Comment: C:\Users\Андрей>go
Go is a tool for managing Go source code.

Usage:

        go command [arguments]

The commands are:

    build       compile packages and dependencies
    clean       remove object files
    doc         run godoc on package sources
    env         print Go environment information
    fix         run go tool fix on packages
    fmt         run gofmt on package sources
    get         download and install packages and dependencies

Comment: install     compile and install packages and dependencies
    list        list packages
    run         compile and run Go program
    test        test packages
    tool        run specified go tool
    version     print Go version
    vet         run go tool vet on packages

Use "go help [command]" for more information about a command.

Additional help topics:

    gopath      GOPATH environment variable
    packages    description of package lists
    remote      remote import path syntax
    testflag    description of testing flags
    testfunc    description of testing functions

Answer (score 1):

[Документация](http://golang.org/doc/install#windows)

> The Go project provides two installation options for Windows users (besides installing from source): a zip archive that requires you to set some environment variables and an experimental MSI installer that configures your installation automatically.

Comment: я это читал и установил, а дальше что не знаю

Comment: то что в разделе «Test your installation»

Comment: запускаешь файл hello.go ничего не происходит, нужно еще что установить наверное

Comment: файл с расширением go запускать не нужно. Его нужно компилировать. А результатом будет exe файл, который как раз и нужно запускать.

Comment: а чем компилировать?

Comment: компилятором, как не удивительно. Но посмотрел на go, он оказывается все умеет красиво - `go run имяфайла.go` - он сам скомпилирует и запустит. Запускать это нужно с консоли, естественно.

Comment: извиняюсь за глупый вопрос
а как в консоль это прописать?

Comment: вот с этого и нужно начинать.

Нажимаем кнопку пуск, там, в поле ввода пишем `cmd` и чуточку ждем. В списке будет `cmd shell`. его и запускаем. Откроется "страшное черное окошко с белыми буковками".

Теперь нужно перейти в рабочий каталог. Для этого пишем `cd имя_каталога`, где имя каталога - это что то вида `C:\Users\пользователь\документы\папка для гоу`. Если в имени пути будут пробелы, то нужно взять в кавычки. и жмем ентр. Имя рабочего пути можно скопировать с проводника. Все, после этого можно будет выполнять вышеуказанные команды.